# Polish transliteration of בֵּית, בֵית, הֵא, פֵּא, פֵא, רֵישׁ

Tags: hebrew, transliteration, yiddish

How would you transliterate the letter names בֵּית, בֵית, הֵא, פֵּא, פֵא, רֵישׁ in order to make it as clear as possible to an English speaker that you were using the Polish pronunciation of צירי as [aj] (so not *bais*, *vais*, *hai*, *pai*, *fai*, *raish* or *bays*, *vays*, *hay*, *pay*, *fay*, *raysh* because an English speaker would be more likely to read those with the Lithuanian [ej])?

Comment: Maybe as _bice, vice, hy, py, fy, ryshe_ / _rishe_?

Comment: I'd like to be consistent with how I render צירי. I'm also using *y* for consonantal י and *i* for חיריק.

Comment: Then _beys, veys, hey, pey, fey, reysh_. Whats the problem?

Comment: No English speaker would be likely to read a transliteration of Hebrew with Lithuanian sounds. The versions with _ai_ would all most likely be pronounced [aɪ] by an English speaker, not [eɪ].

Comment: To Yellow Sky: again, that still might look more like [ej] than [aj] to an English speaker. To Janus Bahs Jacquet: by "Lithuanian" I mean "how Lithuanian Jews traditionally pronounce Hebrew." As for *ai*, compare *aisle* vs. *maid*, *main*, *raid*, *rain*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to your problem is probably using IPA.